# How can I change my NHibernate mapping involving a composite id to execute the expected sql statement?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

I'm using FluentNHibernate and building a system where a `Customer` object exposes several `CustomerProperty` objects, basically a per-customer key-value store.

```cs
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer> {
    public CustomerMap() {
        Table("Customer");
        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.UserName);
        HasMany(x => x.Properties);
    }
}

public class CustomerPropertyMap : ClassMap<CustomerProperty> {
    public CustomerPropertyMap() {
        Table("CustomerProperty");
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Customer, MapData<Customer>.KeyColumn)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Key);

        Map(x => x.Value);
    }
}
```

This works and generates proper NHibernate mappings. I've exported them using the built-in capabilities of FluentNHibernate.

```xml
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" dynamic-update="true" name="Bazinga.Domain.CustomerProperty, Bazinga.Domain, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=108b91ac50cc98b9" table="CustomerProperty">
        <composite-id>
            <key-many-to-one name="Customer" class="Bazinga.Domain.Customer, Bazinga.Domain, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=108b91ac50cc98b9">
                <column name="CustomerId" />
            </key-many-to-one>
            <key-property name="Key" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <column name="Key" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="Value" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <column name="Value" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This mapping, however, generates a sql query that does not visually please me. (I can be pretty pedantic.) NHibernate Profiles shows me that the following query executes.

```sql
SELECT properties0_.CustomerId as CustomerId1_,
       properties0_.[Key]      as Key2_1_,
       properties0_.CustomerId as CustomerId13_0_,
       properties0_.[Key]      as Key2_13_0_,
       properties0_.[Value]    as Value3_13_0_
FROM   CustomerProperty properties0_
WHERE  properties0_.CustomerId = 1337 /* @p0 */
```

There are duplicate references to the `CustomerId` and the `Key` column. How can I remove these and only return a result of three columns (`CustomerId`, `Key`, `Value`)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried both CompositeId fields using .KeyProperty instead .KeyReference?

Comment: .KeyProperty is for basic types while .KeyReference is for, well, references. In this case the Customer property is a reference to another domain type. Using KeyProperty makes things go haywire, the property mapped becomes "Id" (from Customer.Id), exceptions are thrown and everything is unhappy.